# ibeacon related: app icon displayed on lock screen and home button double click in lower left corner, disappeared on ios 10

Tags: ios, icons, ios10, ibeacon

App icon that shows up on the corner when it is in ibeacon proximity, stopped displaying when on ios 10.3 device. 
ibeacon related functions work properly, I send some payload on didEnterRegion and didExitRegion, I can verify that they work. I cannot find the reason app icon not showing up.

Comment: no, i wrote it myself. Is it not clear? Should i rephrase it?

Comment: this might answer your question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43883355/beacon-based-app-suggestion-on-lock-screen-not-shown-in-ios-10

Answer (score 0):

I may have figured it out myself:

To keep the Siri suggestions when you swipe right or down in the home screen, but to remove the icon at the bottom left of the screen when you double click the home button go to Settings > Privacy > Location Services > System Services > Location-Based Suggestions > OFF.

Since I did that I have not seen the little icons.

Comment: Hi Jagathish, it is the other way around, i want that app icon shows up