# Beacon based app suggestion on lock screen not shown in iOS 10

Tags: ios, swift, beacon

My app uses background beacon scanning. I have written `locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()` and `locationManager.startMonitoring(for: region)` in my code. When I open the beacon, the lock screen of my iPad mini (iOS 9.3) shows my APP's icon. However, it's not shown on the lock screen of my iPhone 5s (iOS 10.3).

I have checked the `didDetermineState`, `didEnterRegion`, `didExitRegion` callbacks. All of them works fine on both devices.

Is it a bug or should I do some additional settings to make my APP appear on the lock screen suggestion in iOS 10 device?

Comment: The icon is supposed to show up when the didEnterRegion event fires to launch the app.  Try (1) turning off all beacons with the app in the foreground and waiting 30 secs for regions to exit (2) Kill the app from the task switcher, then (3) turn on a beacon.  Do you see the icon?  If not, repeat this procedure while looking at the logs in XCode -> Devices and look for a log line from your didEnterRegion callback.

Comment: I did what you say, and saw the didEnterRegion callback in the log, but still not see the icon.

Answer (score 1):

The feature that shows a suggested app icon on the lock screen based on a CoreLocation region entry event seems to have been **removed from iOS 10**, although there are inconsistent reports, and [some users with early version of iOS 10 insist they still saw it happening.](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/are-suggested-apps-gone-in-ios-10.2001992/)  In iOS 8-10, there is still a separate [Handoff feature](http://www.itchban.com/full-articles/2014/10/2/os-x-yosemite-ios-8-handoff) that often shows Safari icons on the lock screen, that may be confused with suggested apps.

In my tests, the same BeaconWizard app that monitors for a single CLBeaconRegion has its icon appear on the lock screen when the beacon is turned on in iOS 8.3.

[image]

It does not show up on the lock screen in iOS 10.1.1.

In iOS 10, a similar Siri suggested apps feature appears if you swipe right on the lock screen.  It is unclear what algorithm is used for the suggestions.  Location may be one factor, but I am not able to get apps to consistently appear in this list based on location events.

[image]

Comment: My iOS 10 device still shows suggested app on the lock screen and subtitled "based on your location", although I have no idea why it happens, that app does not use location service.

Comment: Is this the same app mentioned in the question that you said does not work?  If different, note that only one app at a time can have it's icon appear on the lick screen.  You must clear it before a second one will show up.

Comment: No, it is another app from app store.